# Reconcile difference in answers for conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability, simulation

Disclaimer: I am a mechanical engineer, not a statistics guy, so I sometimes miss things.

**Background:**

I have a copy of "Applied Probability Models with Optimization Applications" by Sheldon M. Ross ([link](http://amzn.com/0486673146)) and I am working through the content, making sure that I understand it.

On page 8 it gives the following as an example of conditional probability:

> A prisoner is placed in a cell containing three doors.  The first door leads immediately to freedom.  The second door leads to a tunnel which returns him to the cell after one days travel.  The third door leads to a similar tunnel which returns him to his cell after three days.  Assuming that the prisoner is at all times likely to choose any one of the doors, what is the expected length of time until the prisoner reaches freedom?

It then goes on to say:
$$ E\left[ Y |  X =1 \right ] = 0 $$
$$ E\left[ Y |  X =2 \right ] = 1 + EY $$
$$ E\left[ Y |  X =3 \right ] = 3 + EY $$

From this it concludes:
$$ EY = \frac {1}{3} \left[0+ \left(1+EY\right)+ \left(3+EY\right) \right ] $$
or
$$ EY = 4 $$

I took this, and implemented it in MatLab and ran it a million times.  Here is the code:

```
function conditionalProbEx1

clc;
close all;

y=myfun(1000000);

cdfplot(y)

[mean(y) median(y)]

%my game
function [t]=myfun(n)

if nargin==0
    n=1;
end

t=zeros(n,1);

for i=1:n

    %initialize t
    t(i)=1;
    loops=1; maxloops=200;     test=0;

    while (test==0)&(loops<=maxloops)
        %pick random number
        ind=rand;

        %compute length of time for number
        if ind<=(1/3)
            t(i)=t(i);
            test=1;
            %break
        elseif (ind<=(2/3))&(ind>(1/3))
            t(i)=t(i)+1;
        elseif (ind<=1)&(ind>(2/3))
            t(i)=t(i)+3;
        end

        loops=loops+1;

    end

    %iterate

end

return
```

My values are all integers, but there are a million samples there, so it shouldn't be off much.

When I plot it, I get the following:
[image]

The range of cumulative probabilities of remaining in the cell for only four days goes from 48.06% to 60.42%.  It envelopes the median.  The range of cumulative probabilities of remaining in the cell for exactly three days ranges from 48.06% to 44.38%, or 3.68%.

**Question:**

Why are you nearly 4x more likely to remain in the cell 4 days than you are to remain in the cell 3 days?  Is it because of the "3-days" part of the loop?  It feels fractal-ish, if that makes sense - the recurrence of the asymmetry in the step-size.

How do I train my mechanical intuition to find this reasonable?

Comment: The probability generating function for $Y$ is $1/(3-x-x^3).$ The coefficients in its MacLaurin series will give you *exact* values to work with.

Comment: @whuber - This looks like a variation on a transfer function.  Where can I learn more about it?  I think that a "holy grail" would be a way to relate the Transfer function of a system to variation in its output.  The delta method is a kluge, and I think there might be a better answer from perturbation methods.  I would love to see it, and get to know it well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be off by 1 in reading your graph.  Note that you might get out in zero days.  p[0] = 1/3 or about 33%.

p[1] = 1/3 ^ 2 or about 11%, as you need a 1/3 probability 1-day trip and a 0-day release, but p[2] is quite small at only 1/3 ^ 3 or just under 4%.

p[3] jumps back up to about 12%, and yes that is because of the 3 day loop.  The three day loop allows you to get to this possibility with only two 1/3 probability events (combined probability 1/3 ^2 or 1/9) or four 1/3 probability events (3 one day trips and then release for an additional 1/3 ^ 4 for an additional 1/81), thus a total of 1/9+1/81 or about 12%.

Comment: So if I change my code from "t(i)=1;" to "t(i)=0;" then it shifts the plot to the left, but it does not help the nonsmooth size change become intuitive.